# Smack Push Notification not working

Tags: android, push-notification, xmpp, smack

I am using Smack library to get XMPP pubsub requests in my Android App.
I want to send alert from 1 phone which is received on another phone as push notification popup.

On debugging, control returns null due to this code in Smack 4.2.0 library's ChatManager.java class.

```
 EntityJid userJID = from.asEntityJidIfPossible();
    if (userJID == null) {
        LOGGER.warning("Message from JID without localpart: '" + message.toXML() + "'");
        return null;
    }
```

My from isnt null,ofc... but, my asEntityjidIfPossibe is null.

My Iq is as follows:

```
<iq 
 to="pubsub.foo"
 from="notifier@foo"
 type="set"
 id="1523272621323">

 <pubsub xmlns="http://jabber.org/protocol/pubsub">
 <publish xmlns="http://jabber.org/protocol/pubsub"
  node="/home/foo/notifier/c7215880-a36e-4cb9-bdd3-441cf9c29c31/pqr">

  <item id="item11523272621323">
  <json xmlns="urn:xmpp:json:0">

  {"id":"b7da305d-77c2-422a-9c95-7ec8a347192e",
  "orgId":"c7215880-a36e-4cb9-bdd3-441cf9c29c31",
  "user_id":"f0622ed6-860f-4f4e-9b11-c4ab6cb8cd66",
  "username":"xyz",
  "subject":"Message",
  "body":"hello all",
  "priority":"NORMAL",
  "ack_required":false,
  "users":["pqr"],
  "replyTo":["/home/foo/notifier/c7215880-a36e-4cb9-bdd3-441cf9c29c31/xyz",
  "/home/foo/notifier"]}
  </json>
  </item>
  </publish>
  </pubsub>
  </iq>
```

All I want is to see if message sent is recieved or not? And how to get data to process it...Data is sent perfectly on the server from the sending phone.

On recieving device,
I get this message TWICE,

```
Message from JID without localpart: '<message to='xyz@foo/5301412210663914056363834' from='pubsub.foo'><event xmlns='http://jabber.org/protocol/pubsub#event'><items node='/home/foo/notifier/c7215880-a36e-4cb9-bdd3-441cf9c29c31/xyz'><retract id='item11523351450156'/></items></event></message>'
```

Comment: deliverMessage() method is not executed. The comment in library is,  // The chat could not be created, abort here.   Why does this issue occur?

Comment: Please give a reason for downvote.  I have this unsolved issue. And I am desperately trying to find a solution.

Comment: Hi @Shachi I am new with XMPP and my doubt is it required to enable push notification every time whenever I connect with the server or only once or whenever device token is changed is enough

Comment: @VirendraVarma I sent push notification every time a new msg came. I was making a chat service.